# jquery - add and remove listbox items from hidden field

Tags: jquery, html

I have two listboxes and two buttons to transfer items from one to the other.
I do this view jQuery and the following code:

```
function add() {
        $('#AvailableUsers option:selected').appendTo('#SelectedUsers');
    }
    function remove() {
        $('#SelectedUsers option:selected').appendTo('#AvailableUsers');
    }
```

What I want is, for serialization purposes, to duplicate the items in the second list to a hidden text field. What strcture should I use for the hidden field and how would I go about adding and removing elements from the hidden field?

Answer (score 0):

Use the val() functions.. or am I missing something?

```
$('hidden input selector').val($('second field selector').val());
```